# How do you fix an undefined variable in Python Kivy Programming?

Tags: python, kivy

I am a beginner Kivy user, and I am trying to create a simple clock app. I am getting an error saying that 'Clock' is not defined. How is this possible given that I already created a class called 'ClockApp'?

```
 from kivy.app import App
 from kivy.core.window import Window
 from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex

class ClockApp(App):
    def update_time(self,nap):
         self.root.ids.time.text = strftime('[b]%H[/b]:%M:%S')
    def on_start(self):
         Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_time,1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window.clearcolor = get_color_from_hex('#31240')

ClockApp().run()
```

Comment: It's complaining about Clock (on_start method), not ClockApp!

Answer (score 2):

you import it

`from kivy.clock import Clock`

ClockApp has nothing to do with Clock being defined or undefined...

Comment: Thank you Jordan. That fixed it. I have one last question. Now, I am getting an error saying that strftime is undefined. Where do I import this from?  I am merely following a guide on Kivy book, the author doesn't show the entire program, just fragments so it's sort of difficult to know what's missing in my code.

Comment: `from time import strftime` ... probably